# Calling Windows subsystem for Linux apps through PowerShell/cmd

Tags: linux, windows, bash, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

With recently pushed for Windows insiders build 14316 we have Windows subsystem for Linux (beta) that allows to run Ubuntu Linux CLI software on Windows.
It can be launched by running `bash` command inside Windows PowerShell or by "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" app.

So, my question is about first way. We can launch `bash` from PowerShell, but none other ubuntu CLI application is available from it. How do you make one work? Let's say that I want `zsh` to be available to launch without using bash.

Comment: Is `zsh` available in this new universe? Is it installed? Can you install it? Are those your questions?

Comment: @EtanReisner No, these aren't my questions. Please read second paragraph again. I meant to open up subsystem's application without launching bash first. Installing zsh is same as in ubuntu on real hardware.

Comment: Does running `zsh` (instead of `bash`) once you've installed `zsh` *not* just work for you? If not why not? What happens?

Comment: @EtanReisner It doesn't. That's why I ask here. It simply returns unknown command error, not like I except it to be runnable from powershell, but I want it to be runnable from powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet, according to [Windows Blog: Run Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/):

> Third, note that Bash and Linux tools cannot interact with Windows applications and tools, and vice-versa. So you won’t be able to run Notepad from Bash, or run Ruby in Bash from PowerShell.

More [in Microsoft/CommandLine-Documentation#32](https://github.com/Microsoft/CommandLine-Documentation/issues/32#issuecomment-207806616), which is about the related ability to run win32 commands from within Bash:

> Rest assured, we're going to be looking into the interop story in the future, but we won't be adding this capability in the Windows 10 Anniversary Update timeframe.

You might have some luck with the `-c` option of `bash` to run specific commands.

Comment: Yep, making function that pushes parameters to -c from PowerShell kinda works. For example, `function Bash-Echo($x) { bash -c "echo $x" }`, or even with aliases if no parameters needed. I don't think it's nice solution though but it's fine as temporary.

Comment: Don't think of bash.exe as strictly a bash shell. Instead think of it as a console with access to the Windows Linux Subsystem (WLS). If you apt install zsh as the shell of your choice (you still have to open bash.exe), and select it as your default shell, then zsh will open in the console. If this doesn't make sense, see askubuntu.com or search other Windows Linux Subsystem help. You can also simply type zsh in the Bash console. You cannot open a standalone zsh regardless of the system.

Comment: Starting from Windows versions released since the end of 2016, it is possible (1) to invoke linux programs from the Windows console and (2) to invoke windows programs from the linux console. You may check the WSL [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/10/19/windows-and-ubuntu-interoperability/) and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop).