# bash -c from bat file spawned from exe not a command

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run a batch file that runs `bash -c` (part of windows subsystem for linux/Bash on ubuntu on windows) as a child process of an exe (pidgin), even if the exe is elevated/administrator in Windows the batch file errors:

```
'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The .bat file that I am running is:

```
bash -c "curl --silent -u '''my api key'':' -d type='note' -d body='My Message' -d title='My Subject' 'https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes'"
pause #disable after debugging
```

What I intend to do is have it as a 'buddy pounce' in pidgin so that when I get a message from Nickserv, it will notify me everywhere.

I also tried to execute the command from pidgin directly rather than running as a bash file, but the curl never happens, and I don't get a notification through pushbullet. But if I run the exact same command in CMD or in Run, it will use bash and execute the curl successfully.
[image: pidgin ui of buddy pounce configuration]

I also found this question: [Calling Windows subsystem for Linux apps through PowerShell/cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504784/calling-windows-subsystem-for-linux-apps-through-powershell-cmd) but I'm not sure if it answers that this cannot be done because you clearly can put  a bash command in a bat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the path to C:\Windows\sysnative\bash.exe. Pidgin is 32-bit so it aliases C:\Windows\System32 to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and C:\Windows\sysnative to C:\Windows\System32. It would probably make sense for MS to symlink a bash.exe in SysWOW64 to the real one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried fully specifying the path to the bash shell in your batch file?

If you replace the bash command in your curl.bat file with c:\Windows\System32\bash.exe things may work a little better.  Seems like pidgin doesn't have your full path environment variable available to the process it spawns.

Comment: Wow, that's a great suggestion, but sadly it doesn't work. I've given up on this idea, but it was fun to try out, and test the limits of WSL

Comment: if anyone is actually trying to curl like this I suggest just getting a windows install of curl and run from there